# Sharing two computers on the same network

Tags: network-shares, sharing

I reinstalled a clean install of WIN10 on my 2 computers (1909) and am trying to get them to share files.  I have followed step by step directions (https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/111783-share-files-folders-over-network-windows-10-a.html?s=b2fd866e32def1a9f28b5c4ac9ae6b98) and they still do not allow me access.  It is weird but I can access one external drive from the 2nd computer but that is all.  Needless to say I am very frustrated.

I get "Advanced Sharing...." when I click Share from the File Explorer menu on the drives I have set under properties to share read/write permissions to Everyone.

I changed SMB as shown - I made sure Sharing Wizard was checked - I turned Function Discovery Resource and Provider to Automatic - I have set advanced sharing to "turn on" as shown and I restarted both computers.

And as I said I can access one external drive from one computer off the second but all the other tries give me the error dialog box of the attached pix.

I am at my wits end - this should not be this difficult.

Thanks to all who read and try to help.  Charles

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEFtb.png)

Comment: No one is going to switch between reading your tutorial and your post.  Either include a text description of what you did or a screenshot of what you did. Connecting two PCs on a lan is an old issue and Windows 10 does a good job of connecting PCs. You are going to have to provide more specific reasons for why you have failed to connect your PCs. The tutorial asks a lot more questions.  Do a search for "Set Up File Sharing on a Windows 10 PC" See https://www.tenforums.com/network-sharing/146249-lets-put-together-troubleshooting-list-windows-networking.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps (which I have fully tested) in order and then please let us know the results.

When connecting machines, Home Group is gone (security concerns), SMBv1 is gone, and Network Browsing at the Workstation level is unreliable (gone in completely new machines).

The following instructions enable folder sharing between two Windows 10 Machines

1. Make sure Network Discovery and File / Print Sharing are enabled on both computers
2. Make sure password protected sharing is enabled both computers.
3. If you wish to share by computer name instead of IP address, put an entry in the HOSTS file of the computer you are connecting from with the name and IP address of the main computer.
4. Make sure both computers are in the same WORKGROUP and make sure Wireless connections are Private, not Public.
5. This next step depends on computer user names and passwords. If both computers use the same username and password, you can skip this step, restart both and test.

If the user names are different, do the following. Make a username on Main that is a user name and password of the computer you are connecting from. Use this for permissions on the folders on Main you wish to share. **It is normally quite difficult to share USER folders because Home Group was removed. Use a neutral folder for sharing.**  You can see what happens below

[image]

Again after all the above changes restart and test.

On the computer you are connecting from, open a command prompt and type:

NET USE X: \nameofothercomputer\folder

Press enter and then authenticate with the user name and password credentials.

When you do this, if it does not connect, please let us know the numerical error.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response - I will try this tomorrow and let you know what happens.

Comment: I tried to follow the directions but there were a few things I did not understand.  I have prepared a Word document as PDF in detail with screen shots that you can view or download here [basic links](https://www.chespax.org/1990s)

Comment: 1.   Good   2. Turn Password Protected Sharing ON (not off) 3. Start with addressing the other computer by IP address. 4. Good.  Windows 10 Start, Settings, Network, Status and you can check if Wireless is Private or Public. Ensure Private .  5.  Good. Your screen shots. D: is fine - you are connected. C: is not easily possible (read the final large paragraph I wrote. Move files / folders you wish to share to C:\MainFolder or some such. Basically you have SUCCEEDED and are sharing your files as expected.

Comment: I added a screen shot to my post so that you can see trying to share USER (Desktop) folders is impractical

Comment: I think your questions have been answered and you are able to share folders. Do you have more questions?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by following the directions on this YouTube video on setting security under properties on the drive I wanted to share from one computer to the other and the other way around.  This is the ONLY thing that finally worked.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pl59ODaP6no - thanks for your help.